# Why do we need SIP "100 Trying" response over TCP?

Tags: sip, sip-server, opensips

**SIP over UDP**: It's necessary to have SIP response "100 Trying" for SIP over UDP to shut the Timer-A off that would have been started by caller and hence stopping the re-transmission of the SIP message. Its really important because other responses (provisional and final) might take a while for initial INVITE message as we have to consider the scenario of forking, UE-B not reachable, fallback... etc It might take some time.

**SIP over TCP:** Timer-A will not be started by caller and thus no re-transmission of message. TCP being reliable, not re-transmission required. Even then, why do most implementation sends 100 Trying over TCP ???

Answer (score 2):

There are few reasons that 100 Trying is still needed for SIP over TCP.

1. Having a TCP Connection does not guarantee that the SIP Application is working or if its a SIP - Aware application at all. The 100 Trying provides you the feedback that your request is being processed by a SIP Application.
2. The lack of 100 Trying can also be the right trigger for not just re-transmissions but to re-attempt to maybe a different server in the configuration. You may not want to elapse 32 seconds  for every Server in configuration even when the connection is TCP.
3. In deployment scenarios, if there are elements like a SBC or Load Balancer, the TCP Connection is established with them. The Application behind it can be a different entity and usually these edge elements pass on all messaging or generate messaging to indicate the call in action state.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it makes the SIP stack implementation easier. It makes life easier if the SIP transaction layer is the same irrespective of the SIP transport that is used. If the transaction layer has different rules for different transports that's extra code for no real benefit, i.e. the bandwidth save by not sending the 100 Trying response is negligible in the scheme of things.